# Is it impossible to set up a proxy on the websocket?

Tags: websocket

I'm making a vue project.

The same goes for React.

devServer {proxy:... in webpack settings...Proxy settings work for libraries installed at npmi when } is applied.

but,

`const script = createElement('script');`

`script.src = '/libs/libraryExample.js' // has newWebpack() inside this script`

For libraries that you manually added to, the webpack proxy settings above do not work.

The current situation is

back from vue -> 192.168.0.155:8080

↕ Must be connected to a websocket

Back from cloud server -> 155.2.105.100

In this case, under normal circumstances

Just insert devServer {proxy:'https://155.2.105.100'}

Proxy will also be applied to wss://155.2.105.100.

But if you add it manually like that, it doesn't work as a proxy.

Yeah, let's just customize the library!
I made up my mind

I looked for proxy-related settings in options in new webpack(url, options),

Neither Google nor gpt could give an answer.

`script.src = '/libs/libraryExample.js' // has newWebpack()` inside this script
I've given b multiple options in new Webpack(a,b) inside that script, but...It didn't work.

I've also put in the new webpack (url, {rejectUnauthorized: false }) that's spread on the Internet.

It doesn't seem to work with the current version of Chrome. Or it's an option that only works for xhr, not ws.

Is there any way...?

The library itself is using new webpack, not socket.io , so it's hard to replace it with anything else.

Comment: The "talking to self" style of this question is rather confusing, and I wonder if that will result in it not being answered. I wonder if it could do with some formatting, as there seems to be a lot of information that is not made readable.

Comment: I wonder if a paragraph at the top that summarises your problem might be useful. Are you looking to set up a web server on port 80 and a web socket on port 8080 on the same IP address?